# Cant import matplotlib on python 2.7.5

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, module, importerror

I installed matplotlib using (pip install --user matplotlib) and the installation was successful. when I try to import it using (import matplotlib) in python shell I get this error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import matplotlib
ImportError: No module named matplotlib

I couldn't find another question similar to mine because I'm not using anaconda.

Comment: what os are you on? Most likely you have two versions of python, when you used pip it installed for one interpreter and you are using another when you tried to import matplotlib

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have OSX 10.10.3

Comment: ok so run `which python` and `which -a python`

Comment: the output was /usr/bin/python for both commands

Comment: also /usr/bin/python

Comment: do you have sudo rights? Also add the output for `pip --version`

Comment: umm not sure. i didn't use a sudo command but i thought (--user) gives those rights. pip 7.0.3

Comment: where did pip install matplotlib? `--user` should install somewhere in your home directory. If that is not in your path you won't be able to import the package

Comment: I don't know how to find where its installed but does this help?:  matplotlib in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python

Comment: it should be under your home folder under ~/.local/..

Comment: how do I install it in that folder? thanks

Comment: It should already be there when you used --user, why did you use --user?

Comment: oh, so can you think of any reason why it wouldn't import?

Comment: only that where it installed is not in your pythonpath

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81745/discussion-between-padraic-cunningham-and-drew).

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip uninstall matplotlib` then `python -mpip install matplotlib` see if it helps. Otherwise, i'd recommend using a virtual environment which you can install using `sudo easy_install virtualenv` or `pip install virtualenv` This way you could just install and use `matplotlib` by following these steps:

1. Create a new virtual environment : `user@yourmac$ virtualenv .env` (.env can be any name or directory)
2. Activate it by doing : `user@yourmac$ source .env/bin/activate`
3. Then once it's activated just do a `pip install matplotlib` and use it to your satisfaction.

Hopefully this should solve your problem.